# Salesforce Lightning Aura Controller/Descriptor

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, aura

I've been tweaking around a Salesforce system, bounty hunting precisely, trying to pull out child relationship object using its parent object ID only, but using browser network log HTTP request instead of SOQL etc as I'm not logged in within the Salesforce org nor do I have access to Salesforce's Developer Console.

I've found that "Claim__c" object is listed in Child Relationships of parent object "Case" using this http payload :

```
message={"actions":[{"id":"1;a","descriptor":"aura://RecordUiController/ACTION$getObjectInfo","callingDescriptor":"UNKNOWN","params":{"objectApiName":"Case"}}]}
```

[image: Response where it shows that "Claim__c" is child relationship object of its parent "Case"]

Now what I'm interested in is, how do I craft the next payload so I can pull the child relationship object record named "Claim__c" whose parent record is "Case" (I already have case (parent) record ID, keep that in mind) ? Is there such controller/descriptor for this specific action in salesforce lightning?

So far I've tried these controllers :

```
{"actions":[{"id":"123;a","descriptor":"serviceComponent://ui.force.components.controllers.lists.selectableListDataProvider.SelectableListDataProviderController/ACTION$getItems","callingDescriptor":"UNKNOWN","params":{"entityNameOrId":"Claim__c","layoutType":"FULL","pageSize":100,"currentPage":0,"useTimeout":false,"getCount":false,"enableRowActions":false}}]}

message={"actions":[{"id":"4274;a","descriptor":"serviceComponent://ui.force.components.controllers.relatedList.RelatedListViewDataManagerController/ACTION$getItems","callingDescriptor":"UNKNOWN","params":{"filterName":"Claims__r","pageSize":10,"sortBy":"","limit":1000,"useTimeout":false,"queryLocator":null,"parentRecordId":"5007Q000008YlMKQA0","getCount":false,"isPreview":true,"enableRowActions":false,"offset":0},"storable":true}]}

message={"actions":[{"id":"735;a","descriptor":"aura://RecordUiController/ACTION$getRecordWithFields","callingDescriptor":"UNKNOWN","params":{"recordId":"5007Q000006ViYVQA0","fields":["Case.Claim__c"]}}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't have experience with these kind of bounty hunting ... but how we do that using rest is

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_child_relationships.htm?msclkid=835112a5b04211ec92e2079685dade3a

> /ui-api/records/${recordId}/child-relationships/${relationshipName}

So I tried to convert it to your request

```
message={"actions":[{"id":"1;a","descriptor":"aura://RecordUiController/ACTION$getRecords","callingDescriptor":"UNKNOWN","params":{"recordId":"Id", "child-relationships" : "relationshipName"}}]}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot!!!